# Counting the first element in a nested list

Tags: python

I am trying to count the occurrence of the first element in a nested list:

My nested list looks something like this (this is a truncated list, there are several entries like:  ['powerpc', 'powerpc', '4565975']

```
list = [...
    ['powerpc', 'powerpc', '4565975'],
    ['macs', 'mac', '4565975'], 
    ['einsetzen', 'einsetz', '4565975'],
    ['thema', 'thema', '4565975']
     ...
    ]
```

This is a truncated list, there are several entries like:  ['powerpc', 'powerpc', '4565975'] for example.

So I want to count the occurrences of 'powerpc', 'mac', 'einsetzten' and 'thema' in this case. Additionally I want to merge the nested lists based on the number at the end. So far I couldnt figure out how to merge them. I am still trying to count the elements in the list correctly.

So my expected result is something like this:

```
nl = [['powerpc', 'powerpc', '4565975', 2],
     ['macs', 'mac', '4565975', 5], 
     ['einsetzen', 'einsetz', '4565975', 4],
     ['thema', 'thema', '4565975', 3]
     ]
```

So far I tried this code to count the first element in every nested list:

```
nl = [[x,l.count(x[0])] for l in list for x in set(l)]
```

But this counts every element in the nested list instead of just the first element in the nested list.

This is the output this code produces:

```
nl =        [['powerpc', 0], 
            ['4565975', 0], 
            ['mac', 0], 
            ['macs', 0], 
            ['4565975', 0], 
            ['einsetz', 0], 
            ['einsetzen', 0], 
            ['4565975', 0], 
            ['thema', 0]]
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: I don't understand your logic. How did you arrive at the 5 in `['macs', 'mac', '4565975', 5], ` and you say you want to "merge the nested lists based on the number at the end" but all you seem to have done is insert the count into each nested list.?

Comment: Trying to understand: so your list has multiple entries that start with 'powerpc', for example, and you want to merge them, appending the number of occurrences to the end of each nested list? It's not very clear without the full list, or at least a larger sample to see how you arrived at your result.

Comment: Hi @DavidBuck,  sorry for the confusion. The code I posted is how far got. But I want that result in the end.

Comment: Hi @Ahndwoo, thats exactly ehat I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understand of your question, which may be wrong, the following should give you the desired output:

```
from itertools import groupby
# From what I understand, your full list looks something like this
lst = [
        ['powerpc', 'powerpc', '4565975'],
        ['macs', 'mac', '4565975'], 
        ['einsetzen', 'einsetz', '4565975'],
        ['thema', 'thema', '4565975'],
        ['powerpc', 'powerpc', '4565975'],
        ['macs', 'mac', '4565975'], 
        ['einsetzen', 'einsetz', '4565975'],
        ['thema', 'thema', '4565975'],
        ['powerpc', 'powerpc', '4565975'],
        ['macs', 'mac', '4565975'], 
        ['einsetzen', 'einsetz', '4565975'],
        ['thema', 'thema', '4565975']
      ] 
sorted_lst = sorted(lst)
n1 = [l + [len(list(g))] for l, g in groupby(sorted_list)]
print(n1)
# [['einsetzen', 'einsetz', '4565975', 3], ['macs', 'mac', '4565975', 3],['powerpc', 'powerpc', '4565975', 3], ['thema', 'thema', '4565975', 3]]
```

I can't guarantee the output without seeing your actual list, but my tests came out with the result that I expected. This method has two components. The first component is sorting the list. By default, it will sort the list based on the first entry in the nested list, so no need to pass a sorting key. Now `sorted_lst` has all of your list items organized alphabetically based on the first entry in each list. The next step is to use `itertools.groupby` to group similar items together, and count how much of each there is. Then we rebuild the list, appending the count of each element to the end of that element. You can read more about `itertools.groupby` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: @S3DEV Extended the list and added my output

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the link @Ahndwoo. This worked great!